# How do i implement a colour code for a xml layout in android, everytime users opens it, it shows a different colour for the background?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I am making a home page acttivity, it will comprise of 6 buttons, and all buttons will be white.

I want a dynamic background, which changes colors when it is opened, different colour every single time, user exits and returns back.

Answer (score 0):

For an idea,

1. Define set of colours (10) in a xml file.
2. Use HashMap to store some integer (0-9) as the key and color name as the value.
3. select a random integer between 0-9 , and get the relevant colour from the HashMap and assign to your buttons

Comment: Ok, any elaborations on it